# Calculating probability with multiple random variables

Tags: probability

Consider a communication system with input $X$ and output $Y$. Let the input $X$ be a Bernoulli(1/2) random variable; that is $P(X=0)=P(X=1)= 1/2$. The input represents the transmitted bit.  The output random variable $Y$ represents the signal at the receiver and depends on the value of the input $X$. Conditioned on $X=0$, $Y$ is conditionally an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda_0$. Conditioned on $X=1$, $Y$ is conditionally an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda_1$. Based on $Y$, the receiver makes an estimate, ${\hat X}$, of the transmitted bit $X$ via the following rule

${\hat X}$=$\begin{cases}1 & 0\leq Y <1 \\ 0 & Y \geq 1\end{cases}$

Compute $P({\hat X} = 1)$.

So I define $P(Y=y|X=0)=\lambda_0e^{\lambda_0y}$ and $P(Y=y|X=1)=\lambda_1e^{\lambda_1y}$. Then can I say that $P({\hat X} = 1)=\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{\lambda_1}) + \frac{1}{2}(1-e^{\lambda_0})$ by taking the CDF of the exponential functions.

Compute $P({\hat X} \neq X)$ - the probability that the receiver makes an incorrect estimate of the transmitted bit.

Can anyone offer any advice or start a bit of the problem so I can see what I need to do?

This is a practice final for my probability and random processes course, unfortunately with no solution.

Comment: Please do not edit the question to nonsense. The question and solution may be useful to others. Also, the edit history is publicly visible, so changing it to nonsense doesn't hide the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've figured out the first half of the problem, the second half should be just an extension. The probability that the receiver makes an incorrect estimate of the transmitted bit is obtained as follows:$$\mathbb{P}[X\ne \hat{X}]=\mathbb{P}[Y<1 \mid X=0]\mathbb{P}[X=0] +\mathbb{P}[Y>1 \mid X=1]\mathbb{P}[X=1] .$$ where the first half of the expression corresponds to the probability of the receiver making an error when $X=0$ is transmitted and the second half for the $X=1$ case. All you need to do is to compute the individual probabilities and sum them up properly. 
 
The key thing in these kind of problems to remember is the fact that the Probability of error depends entirely upon the decision rule that you define to detect the transmitted symbol and most often this rule is derived for minimizing the probability of error. Such a rule that minimizes the probability of error in detection is known as the Maximum a-posteriori detection rule.

Comment: That makes sense. I believe the first half of the problem is just $P({\hat X} = 1)=\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{\lambda_1}) + \frac{1}{2}(1-e^{\lambda_0})$  and the second half is just the solution you offered. Thanks!

Comment: Yes the answer you've obtained for the first half is correct.